# Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have the following code which works fine in Excel 2007.

However, it gives the following error on Excel 2010:

> Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set.

Any ideas how to fix ? I've checked other posts with no luck.

UPDATE: note that the code works fine if the workbook that contains the vba code is the activeworkbook.

But what I am doing is opening ANOTHER workbook, and then press F3  (which runs this code). It is then when it fails. So basically iif workbook with the code is active, it works, if it is another workbook which is active, it gives the error.

```
Sub Process_current_Sheet()


        Dim WS_Count As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim sheet_name As String

         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         nameofworkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name


         ' Begin the loop.
         For i = 1 To WS_Count

            If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name, "xxx") > 0 Then
                    sheet_name1 = activeWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name               
            End If


        Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `ActiveWorkbook` in your `If` statement. Btw, is this the entire code? I bet not. Make sure you have `Next` and `End If` in place.

Comment: Can you post all your code? This will be helpful for us.

Comment: I don't think you've provided the section of code that was actually throwing that error. Even after closing off the `If` and `For` statements (and declaring `nameofworkbook`) that code works fine in xl2010.

Comment: I have updated code. note that I have not showed all the code within the loop. The error is on the line WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

Comment: @user1135218 : You have 2 `End If` for only one `If`, I'm surprised it doesn't give you an error... Is that an Add-In code?

Comment: sorry, just taken out. my apologies for having two end if. That was not the error.

Comment: Please disregard. Problem found. The other workbook had macros button on (was expecting to press activate or not macros). if you don't then you get this error. If you press the macro button, button dissapears and all fine.

Answer (score 1):

Problem found. 
The second workbook I have open and is the activeworkbook, had a macro behind too, so it was **waiting for the user to press the macro activate/not macros**....

If you don't, you get the error mentioned... 
if You activate the macros on that workbook (macro button not longer shown) then my macro works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the solution, but this will help to confirm who the culprit is at least (tell us if there is an error, and if there is, which error and on which line) :

```
Sub Process_current_Sheet()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer, _
        i As Integer, _
        sheet_name As String, _
        wB As Workbook

    Set wB = ActiveWorkbook

    WS_Count = wB.Worksheets.Count
    nameofworkbook = wB.Name

    ' Begin the loop.
    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        If InStr(wB.Worksheets(i).Name, "xxx") > 0 Then
            sheet_name1 = wB.Worksheets(i).Name
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I found the problem, was related to the 2nd workbook expecting macros to be activated. Sorry for that.

Comment: @user1135218 : No problem, we just couldn't know that it was the issue. But you can validate you own answer as it was the right solution (I edited it a bit for readability but you can improve it yourself)